# Findstr: Search list of strings in folder of txt files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I'm trying to use FINDSTR to search through a folder full of text files, using a text file of strings, then output to results.txt

The text file of strings contains 3,200 lines, each containing an authors name and associated book title. Examples:

```
George Orwell 1984
H. G. Wells War of the Worlds
Isaac Asimov I, Robot
```

I also have a folder containing a dozen text lists of ebook filenames (Some of the lists have over 500K lines.), for example:

```
George Orwell - 1984 (epub).rar
H G Wells - War of the Worlds (pdf).rar
Isaac Asimov - [Robot 0.1] - I, Robot (Mobi).rar
```

I need to search the text files of filenames for the 3,200 author and titles, and output the results to a 3rd text list.

The filenames also contain other stuff like series info, format, etc, so I'm looking for any lines that contain those authors names and titles but are not exact matches to the search strings, as in my examples above.

This is what I've tried. It matches exact strings OK but I cannot see how to make it find the filenames that contain other stuff as well as all the words in the search strings.

```
findstr /g:C:\strings.txt *.txt >>C:\results.txt
```

Can anyone please help me out with the code. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach won't work that way. By default findstr is RegEx based where each search with spaces in it is ORed. So `George Orwell 1984` will match any line in the current .txt file containing `George` or `Orwell` or `1984`. Also [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Show your own coding attempt and we might be able to pinpoint your errors and direct you to a soltution.

Comment: `findstr` cannot perform approximate searches, so if none of the search strings (author and title) exactly match (besides the case), how should one find files? Perhaps you adapt the list file `C:\strings.txt` and do the search afterwards...

Comment: LotPings, If you'd actually read my post you would have seen I did post my own coding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This find in files requires a regular expression search because of the strings in `strings.txt` do not exist 1:1 in *.txt files.

It is necessary to change the strings in `strings.txt` from

```
George Orwell 1984
H. G. Wells War of the Worlds
Isaac Asimov I, Robot
```

to

```
George.*Orwell.*1984
H.*G.*Wells.*War.*of.*the.*Worlds
Isaac.*Asimov.*I.*Robot
```

This can be done by opening `strings.txt` in a text editor with Perl regular expression support and run from top of the file a Perl regular expression replace all with search string `[^\w\r\n]+` and replace string `.*`. The search expression results in searching for one or more characters not being a word character, a carriage return or a line-feed.

Then it is possible to use:

```
findstr /I /R /G:C:\Temp\strings.txt *.txt >>C:\Temp\results.txt
```

`strings.txt` and `results.txt` should not be in current directory containing the *.txt files searched by **FINDSTR** or a different file extension than `.txt` is used for these two files.

Answer (score -2):

Find some string inside all text files in current directory and store results in file:

```
for %i in (*.txt) do (find /i "giff" < "%i" && (echo : %i & echo -)) >> results.txt
```

Tested in Win 10